# How do you alphabetize a json file in php by an element?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, usort

Currently, I have this json file:

```
{"root":[
       {
          "companyname":"Zcompany",
          "style":"Dstyle",
          "price":"$ 99.99"
       },
       {
          "companyname":"Scompany",
          "style":"Gstyle",
          "price":"$ 129.99"
       },
       {
          "companyname":"Fcompany",
          "style":"Estyle",
          "price":"$ 19.99"
       }
    ]
}
```

I created a table using php, but I want to be able to alphabetize the json file by the company name.

I just cant get `usort` to work. Im pretty sure its because I'm using the usort wrong for the type of json I have.

But, I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
//read json file
$file = 'root.json';
$filedata = file_get_contents($file);
$root = json_decode($filedata,true);

function build_sorter($key) {
  return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
      return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
  };
}

usort($root, build_sorter('root'));

foreach($root['root'] as $p) {
  //prints table from the json file
  echo '<tr><br>
    <td>'.$p['companyname'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$p['style'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$p['price'].'</td>'.
    '</tr>';
  ;
}
?>
```

When I run the code above, I get the error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 14// the line that starts the foreach.
>
> Undefined index: root in on line 14// same line that starts the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense trying to sort it out thru the `root` key, its the parent key, use the keys in the inner levels (`price, style, etc..`):

```
usort($root['root'], build_sorter('price'));
```

Comment: in the for loop I think changing it to `$root[0]` might work too.

Comment: @l'L'l changing it to `$root[0]` after `usort()` which actually reindexed it to numeric (the root) still doesn't make sense, its still the same order in the end, why would you sort it thru the parent array, there's nothing to sort out there, the inner dimensions are the ones needed to be sorted out

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the array after it was already sorted... long day :)

Comment: Thanks ghost, you are a genius. That fixed the problem. And yea, it DOESN'T make sense to sort through root. While i was replacing some of the code I accidentally changed the companyname into root. adding the $root['root'] fixed it